# What is the alternate solution to work the below code in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
<span class="new" style="vertical-align:middle;">Choose username:</span>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<input type="submit" name="signup" value="Check" class="button height"/>
</form>
```

css:

```
#username{
background: url(/image/correct.jpg) no-repeat;
background-position:95% 8px;
background-size:18px;
padding-right: 35px;
vertical-align:bottom;
height:27px;

}
```

The problem is background-size and background-position does not work in internet explorer. What could be the alternative? I used

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/correct.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='image/correct.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

What is the solution plz?

Comment: What is the size of the image: `correct.jpg`?

Comment: What is the issue are you getting in IE?

Comment: background-position percentage (as a whole number) works in IE, but background-size doesn't. It isn't very clear what you are trying to do, my guess i that you are over engineering this and don't need background-size. But to know I think we need an example on jsfiddle or a link to a stripped down version. - or at least a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: @PraveenKumar if using filter image size is 95% as that of input box without filter image is not at all displaying.

Comment: @infensus i am trying to add a image in input box

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 Do one thing. Give some padding right on the image and give as `right center` for the position. That's the better way to tackle this.

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 I have posted it as an answer. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar image is as large as input box

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 Resize the image to fit. Use an image editor. Hopefully it is a single image. i.e., only one image in the `18 x 18` and resize it to `15 x 15` or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Internet Explorer doesn't support `background-size`!

The property, `background-size` is not supported by Internet Explorer. My best solution would be, giving the image a right padding, transparent or whatever the background colour is, using an image editor (Paint, or Photoshop) and then aligning the background image to `right center`.

```
#username{
    background: url(/image/correct.jpg) no-repeat right center;
    padding-right: 35px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 27px;
}
```

Comment: i had given right padding already and given right center now but the result is same...Thanks.

Comment: Dude, right padding not in the CSS, but in the image. `:)` Can you post a screenshot? Or is there a public site, where we can see it?

Comment: how to give that in image since it is background?